# Python tkinter inserting string in texttbox out of a function

Tags: python, function, listbox

Trying to add text from a function into a textfield, but can't figure out how.
Every time when the Start button is clicked it should add text to the textfield.

```
import Tkinter

class GuiCreate:

    def __init__(self,parent):

        #Textbox
        window  = Frame(width=620, height=50)
        window.place(x=25,y=320)
        vscroll = Scrollbar(window)
        hscroll = Scrollbar(window, orient='horizontal')
        #  create instance variable with "self"
        self.listbox = Text(window, height=10) 
        self.listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
        vscroll.config(command=self.listbox.yview, relief=SUNKEN)
        hscroll.config(command=self.listbox.xview, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=vscroll.set, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.listbox.config(xscrollcommand=hscroll.set)

        f7 = Frame(width=30, height=20)
        f7.place(x=20,y=260)
        srcButton = Button(f7, text="START", command=self.startProcess)
        srcButton.pack(side='left')


    def startProcess(self):
        textinsert = 'abcdefg'
        self.listbox.insert('end', textinsert)


root = Tk()
root.title("Clipfinder")
root.geometry('650x550+200+100')
root.configure(background = 'gray')
gui=GuiCreate(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Getting the Error: AttributeError: GuiCreate instance has no attribute 'listbox'

How can I send the string out of a function into the textbox?
THX

Comment: Make sure `self.listbox = Text(window, height=10)` is called before you try and `.pack` it.

Comment: I'm confused, window is now not defined... self.listbox = Text(window, height=10) 
NameError: name 'window' is not defined.  Sorry Objects is a little bit new to me

Comment: updated the post. Now getting NameError: name 'window' is not defined.

Comment: you had other references to `listbox` instead of the `self.listbox` in the scrollbar variables.

Comment: yes i added the self also at the vscroll.config(command=self.listbox.yview, relief=SUNKEN).  It is exactly now as shown here.

Comment: No, getting following Error now:   File "Clipfinder_GUI.py", line 164, in GuiCreate
    self.listbox = Text(window, height=10) 
NameError: name 'window' is not defined

Comment: I've edited my post and I'm able to run that code without issue?

Comment: if I copy paste this part here iinto a new program, it is working also, but getting with my hole program this error... thats interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the `listbox` as an instance variable with `self`:

```
from Tkinter import *  

class GuiCreate:

    def __init__(self,parent):

        #Textbox
        window  = Frame(width=620, height=50)
        window.place(x=25,y=320)
        vscroll = Scrollbar(window)
        hscroll = Scrollbar(window, orient='horizontal')
        #  create instance variable with "self"
        self.listbox = Text(window, height=10) 
        self.listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
        vscroll.config(command=self.listbox.yview, relief=SUNKEN)
        hscroll.config(command=self.listbox.xview, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=vscroll.set, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.listbox.config(xscrollcommand=hscroll.set)

        f7 = Frame(width=30, height=20)
        f7.place(x=20,y=260)
        srcButton = Button(f7, text="START", command=self.startProcess)
        srcButton.pack(side='left')


    def startProcess(self):
        textinsert = 'abcdefg'
        self.listbox.insert('end', textinsert)


root = Tk()
root.title("Clipfinder")
root.geometry('650x550+200+100')
gui = GuiCreate(root)
root.configure(background = 'gray')
root.mainloop()
```

You can learn more about classes and object-orient programming in python [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks), a few paragraphs down it 
touches upon using `self`.

Comment: then i get :  self.listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: seems like not... would: self.listbox = Text(parent) do this? sorry, don't know it...

Comment: @rainer the `window` variable is local to your init which means you won't be able to reference it in other class methods.

Comment: window itself is not referenced else, or is that connected because its the frame of the textbox?

Comment: @rainer Its tough to say without seeing more of the code.

Comment: It is fine now... THX a lot!!! There's a strange formatting bug in geany. Changed it in Gedit and its now working...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    #Textbox
    window  = Frame(width=620, height=50)
    window.place(x=25,y=320)
    vscroll = Scrollbar(window)
    hscroll = Scrollbar(window, orient='horizontal')
    self.listbox = Text(window, height=10)
    self.listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
    vscroll.config(command=self.listbox.yview, relief=SUNKEN)
    hscroll.config(command=self.listbox.xview, relief=SUNKEN)
    self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=vscroll.set, relief=SUNKEN)
    self.listbox.config(xscrollcommand=hscroll.set)

    f7 = Frame(width=30, height=20)
    f7.place(x=20,y=260)
    srcButton = Button(f7, text="START", command=self.startProcess)
    srcButton.pack(side='left')
```

Forgot to add listbox as an attribute. Otherwise it is just local to the init method..